# Taking instance of EntityManager Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am using spring and repository level for connection to the database. I am using  EntityManagerFactory and the jpa repository. My config:

```
    @Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.project.models");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return em;
}
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        EntityManagerFactory emf){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

But now I have a case where I want to use the EntityManager's create method. How can I take an instance of it and also where, when I am using the Jpa repository and have no concrete class for it, that implements the methods?

I am using a repository that extends JpaRepository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Chat, Integer> {
}
```

and then using it in my service:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyServiceImpl(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }
```

Should I make an abstract class that implements MyRepository so I don't have to implement all JpaRepository's methods and take the instance of the EntityManager there and how can I do it?

Comment: _But now I have a case where I want to use the EntityManager's create method_ Maybe you want to show how exactly you would use it?

Comment: @pirho I just want to use the EntityManager's create method instead of the factory's save.  It is pretty straight forward you create entity in the database. With Jpa repository save method will create or update so if there is already a entity in the database it won't throw an exception.

Comment: create() = persist()?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would just inject `EntityManager` where ever you need it. Like:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

and just use method `persist(..)` like:

```
em.persist(myChatObject);
```

so there should not be a need for any special handling.